react-native-branch android app crashes on launch [branch.io]
I have integrated branch.io in my react native for deep linking.
On iOS platform, The deep links are working perfectly fine but when I am integrating android SDK app crashes on launch.
MainActivity.kt
package com.mypkg

import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity
import com.facebook.react.ReactActivityDelegate
import com.facebook.react.defaults.DefaultNewArchitectureEntryPoint.fabricEnabled
import com.facebook.react.defaults.DefaultReactActivityDelegate
import io.branch.rnbranch.*
import android.content.Intent
class MainActivity : ReactActivity() {

  /**
   * Returns the name of the main component registered from JavaScript. This is used to schedule
   * rendering of the component.
   */
  override fun getMainComponentName(): String = "mypkg"

  /**
   * Returns the instance of the [ReactActivityDelegate]. We use [DefaultReactActivityDelegate]
   * which allows you to enable New Architecture with a single boolean flags [fabricEnabled]
   */
  override fun createReactActivityDelegate(): ReactActivityDelegate =
      DefaultReactActivityDelegate(this, mainComponentName, fabricEnabled)

  override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    RNBranchModule.initSession(getIntent().getData(), this)
}

  override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent?) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent)
    setIntent(intent)
    RNBranchModule.reInitSession(this)
  }
}


MainApplication.kt
package com.mypkg

import android.app.Application
import com.facebook.react.PackageList
import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication
import com.facebook.react.ReactHost
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage
import com.facebook.react.defaults.DefaultNewArchitectureEntryPoint.load
import com.facebook.react.defaults.DefaultReactHost.getDefaultReactHost
import com.facebook.react.defaults.DefaultReactNativeHost
import com.facebook.react.flipper.ReactNativeFlipper
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader
import io.branch.rnbranch.*
class MainApplication : Application(), ReactApplication {

  override val reactNativeHost: ReactNativeHost =
      object : DefaultReactNativeHost(this) {
        override fun getPackages(): List<ReactPackage> =
            PackageList(this).packages.apply {
              // Packages that cannot be autolinked yet can be added manually here, for example:
              // add(MyReactNativePackage())
            }

        override fun getJSMainModuleName(): String = "index"

        override fun getUseDeveloperSupport(): Boolean = BuildConfig.DEBUG

        override val isNewArchEnabled: Boolean = BuildConfig.IS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED
        override val isHermesEnabled: Boolean = BuildConfig.IS_HERMES_ENABLED
      }

  override val reactHost: ReactHost
    get() = getDefaultReactHost(this.applicationContext, reactNativeHost)

  override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    RNBranchModule.getAutoInstance(this)
    SoLoader.init(this, false)
    if (BuildConfig.IS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED) {
      // If you opted-in for the New Architecture, we load the native entry point for this app.
      load()
    }
    RNBranchModule.enableLogging();
    ReactNativeFlipper.initializeFlipper(this, reactNativeHost.reactInstanceManager)
  }
}


AndroidManifest.xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
  <application android:name=".MainApplication" android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" android:allowBackup="false" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.wallet.api.enabled"
    android:value="true" />
    <activity 
      android:name=".MainActivity"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode"
      android:launchMode="singleTask"
      android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
      android:exported="true">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
      </intent-filter>

      <!-- Handling scheme deep links -->
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <data android:scheme="mypkg"/>
      </intent-filter>


      <!-- Handling 'http' and 'https' schemes -->
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="http" />
        <data android:scheme="https" />
        <data android:host="1234.test-app.link" />
      </intent-filter>

    <!-- AutoVerify for specific paths (/events, /profile, /settings) -->
    <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:host="1234.test-app.link" android:scheme="https" android:pathPrefix="/events" />
        <data android:host="1234.test-app.link" android:scheme="https" android:pathPrefix="/profile" />
        <data android:host="1234.test-app.link" android:scheme="https" android:pathPrefix="/settings" />
    </intent-filter>

    <!-- AutoVerify for /event path (New) -->
      <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:host="1234.test-app.link" android:scheme="https" android:pathPrefix="/event" />
      </intent-filter>
    
        <meta-data android:name="io.branch.sdk.BranchKey" android:value="key_test" />
        <meta-data android:name="io.branch.sdk.BranchKey.test" android:value="key_test" />
        <meta-data android:name="io.branch.sdk.TestMode" android:value="false" />
    </activity>
  </application>
</manifest>

Gradle (App)
dependencies {
    // The version of react-native is set by the React Native Gradle Plugin
    implementation 'io.branch.sdk.android:library:5.8.0'
    implementation("com.facebook.react:react-android")
    implementation("com.facebook.react:flipper-integration")

    if (hermesEnabled.toBoolean()) {
        implementation("com.facebook.react:hermes-android")
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }
}


I have checked ADB Logcat and this is what I found

Process: com.mypkg, PID: 19133
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.mypkg.MainApplication: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:7110)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:259)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2208)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:233)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:344)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8249)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:589)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1071)
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:463)
at android.content.res.Resources.getString(Resources.java:556)
at io.branch.referral.BranchUtil.readBranchKey(BranchUtil.java:113)
at io.branch.referral.Branch.getAutoInstance(Branch.java:385)
at io.branch.rnbranch.RNBranchModule.getAutoInstance(RNBranchModule.java:106)
at com.mypkg.MainApplication.onCreate(MainApplication.kt:38)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1225)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:7103)

According to the error, the SDK is unable to get the key but I have defined the key in my manifest and also in strings.xml I have attached other core files for the reference.

The error you are seeing will only show when the Branch Key is invalid or not added. Please cross-check your Branch key implementation on the android manifest file with the below documentation.
https://help.branch.io/developers-hub/docs/android-basic-integration
